# Building workspace hangs at 50% invoking JSHintProblemChecker on </projectname>: Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, jshint, nodeclipse

Recently installed nodeclipse plugin. Before that, things were normal. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks for your time in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, Nodeclipse plugin itself does not have JSHint. But it may be suggested to install from Nodeclipse update site http://www.nodeclipse.org/updates/

You should check and update your questions with:

- what and how exactly you installed (e.g. what exact marketplace entry, or downloaded package )
- what is your `.project` file content

I guess you selected to install http://github.eclipsesource.com/jshint-eclipse/.
Check issues there, raise yours https://github.com/eclipsesource/jshint-eclipse

Comment: Paul, Thanks for taking your time to answer this. You are right. I now see that Nodeclipse itself does not have JSHint. I tried to update it from the following link: http://www.nodeclipse.org/updates. I later had to remove the JSHint and reinstall it from http://github.eclipsesource.com/jshint-eclipse as suggested by you. It now builds fine. I am not seeing the JSHint error stopping the workspace from being built anymore. Thank you! I am new to Stackoverflow, looks like I could not upvote your answer as useful without having the minimum 15 reputations.